# Wrong print out statement in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

The Question:

5.Now write the function is_odd(n) that returns True when n is odd and False otherwise.

Finally, modify it so that it uses a call to is_even to determine if its argument is an odd integer.

I had to write a function for is_even(n) that returns True when n even and False otherwise. Here is my code:

```
def is_even(n):
    return n % 2 == 0



def is_odd(n):
    if is_even(n):
        print "This is an even integer."
    else:
        print "This is an odd integer."
    return n % 2 != 0
```

My Question:
I am a total beginner and find programming very hard but I love it for some reason, but why does this not work? I defined the function is_even(n) and is_odd(n), put is_even(n) into the is_odd(n) function, wrote and if/else else statement making if the function is_even is equal to true it should print out it is an even integer... When I put in is_odd(3); it prints out "This is an even integer" and returns True even though it should print out "This is an odd integer."

Update:

I changed my code to this and works fine.

```
def is_even(n):
    return n % 2 == 0

def is_odd(n):
    if is_even(n) == False:
        print "This is an odd integer."

    return n % 2 != 0
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code you proposed not working (although `== True` is redundant here and you could just write `if is_even(n)`), and everything to do with you either (a.) mixing tabs and spaces or (b.) indenting that if by a different amount of spaces than you indented other blocks above it.

Comment: Yes, you are right I asked the question first and modified the code to where the function call inside the function worked and didn't come back to this to change the question asked. I double checked the mixing and matching and used only tabs no spaces and also indented everything by 4 spaces yet still receiving same error

Comment: I think you missed something because if what you said were true it would work. Try changing all your tabs to spaces just to be sure.

Comment: I started a new slate and retyped everything in and it did work so no indentation errors, but when I did test the code putting in  is_odd(3) I got "That is an even integer" and true.. even though it should read "That is an odd integer."

Comment: Pretty sure it's just another typo. The code above is correct and works for me in Python 2.7.

Comment: Strictly speaking you're not following directions because it does call `is_even` but it doesn't use it to determine the result. Instead of printing 'this is even/odd' you should just return True or False in your if statement. If `is_odd` is already going to depend on `is_even` it doesn't need to redo the modulo test.

Comment: I think my code did what you were talking about besides redoing the mod test.

Comment: Yeah the thing I hate about these books for learning things is you have no one to ask or clarify the questions that you are working on. I think I am more confused on the question being asked which messes me up when I code. When I am writing the if is_even(n) == False, is that not making a call to that function is_even?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're encountering `IndentationError` because you're being inconsistent with your indentation. As soon as you indent in Python, you have created a new block. You do this after block-introducing keywords, like `if`, `while`, `for`, etc. Python doesn't care how many spaces or tabs or whatever you use before your first block, but once you make the choice the first time, you must keep using the same number. I've added a line to your posted code to show you:

[image: Screenshot of code in question]

See how the r in return aligns with the f in if? It needs to align with the i. In this example your if is not at the proper indentation level relative to the first block, producing the error in question.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I need a tutorial on stackoverflow or how to write the code effectively within stack. My code in NotePad++ shows the right indentation but when I transfer it to stack the indentations mess up. But you did answer my question.

Comment: I've never tried [this one](http://markdowntutorial.com/) but it looks promising. There's always [the original reference](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics) but I find that website hard to read. Maybe I should also recommend something like Evernote Clearly for that one. :) Anyway, glad I helped.